# SQL order by length for multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to sort by `order by length` in multiple columns. My code is working for one column, but it's not working with multiple columns.

**This is working**

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id,demo1,demo2 FROM $table_name ORDER BY LENGTH(demo1) DESC");
```

**It's not working**

```
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id,demo1,demo2 FROM $table_name ORDER BY LENGTH(demo1),LENGTH(demo2) DESC");
```

Comment: What is the defference between _demo1_  and  _demo2_ ?

Comment: do you receive an error or the result is not as expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(demo1), demo1 DESC,
         LENGTH(demo2), demo2 DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The results are ordered by the first column, then the second, and so on for as many columns as the ORDER BY clause includes. If you want any results sorted in descending order, your ORDER BY clause must use the DESC keyword directly after the name or the number of the relevant column.
If you have not understood properly..and
Before voting down my answer... Can I see your table result please?